# Как удалить многострочный текст между тэгами?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, perl, sed

Как убрать весь многострочный текст между тэгами описания?

```
  <description>
  Туалетная вода-спрей 
  &lt;br&gt;ВОСТОЧНЫЙ ФУЖЕР
  &lt;br&gt;Мужчина в стиле ориентирован на успех, целеустремлен и созидателен. Мужественность, достоинство, уверенность – его главные черты,    наряду с чувственностью и романтичностью. Он любит комфорт, красивые вещи,   роскошную жизнь и выражает себя в классическом пок$
 &lt;br&gt;Ключевые слова: Уверенный, динамичный, мужественный, благородный,  элегантный, статусный, успешный
</description>
```

Вот этот вариант удаляет только те, которые в одной строке:

```
sed 's#\(<description>\).*\(</description>\)#\1'xxxxx'\2#g' test.xml > test2.xml
```

Александр Баракин предложил вот такой вариант:

```
$ sed '/<description>/,/<\/description>/{//!d}' test.xml > test2.xml
```

но текст не удаляется между тэгами в таком примере:
[Пример](http://pastebin.com/bm31r1sh)

Comment: Перестать маяться фигнёй, и использовать адекватные инструменты для работы с XML?

Comment: Согласен, нашел одну утулиту: https://github.com/miku/xmlcutty

Comment: может подскажете что то похожее, но только чтобы наоборот, не выбирать нужные элементы для вырезки, а с вырезкой ненужных?

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795/10105

Answer (score 3):

для данного конкретного случая, например, [так](https://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/sed-delete-the-lines-lying-in-between-two-patterns/):

```
$ sed '/<description>/,/<\/description>/{//!d}' test.xml > test2.xml
```

---

но лучше, действительно, воспользоваться более подходящим инструментом для работы с *xml*.

---

если вдруг и строки-ограничители требуется убрать, то `{//!d}` надо заменить просто на `d`:

```
$ sed '/<description>/,/<\/description>/d' test.xml > test2.xml
```

---

**дополнение**

для удаления текста (в той же строке) и после начального тега, и перед конечным, программу для *sed*, естественно, придётся значительно удлинить:

```
$ sed '/<description>/,/<\/description>/{//!d;s/\(<description>\).*/\1/;s/.*\(<\/description>\)/\1/}' test.xml > test2.xml
```

поэтому ещё раз напомню, что для обработки *xml* лучше воспользоваться каким-нибудь более специализированным инструментом.

Comment: спасибо, но Ваш пример к сожалению не удаляет описания...

Comment: проверил: удаляет строки между двумя указанными строками. как и написано в вашем вопросе. а вам и строки-ограничители надо убрать?

Comment: в примере выше, мне пришлось для форматирования вставить тэги в начале строки. В исходном файле тэги не обязательно в начале строки. Может в этом причина? Спасибо

Comment: 1. в приведённом вами примере в первой строке есть символы до искомой строки `<description>`. 2. собственно, в приведённой мною программе для *sed* вообще нет никаких привязок к началу/концу строки. 3. я дополнил ответ на случай, если надо удалять и строки-ограничители.

Comment: Извините, я Вам изначально дал неправильный пример, вернее формат здесь немного исказился.

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но как только закрывающейся тэг расположен вот так http://pastebin.com/5WDNxw0N. потом уже не работает.

Comment: @AlexanderGross, объясните, что для вас означает «потом уже не работает». желательно прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/538563/edit) ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Текст вопроса исправил, спасибо.

Comment: @AlexanderGross, я дополнил ответ.